# "memset"ting a struct causes printf to print struct member longer than its limit

Tags: c, struct, gdb, memset

I observed this issue in a very large C program.

The structure declaration is:

```
struct kc910InputParms {
    char inStream[71];
}
```

In the program, when there is `memset` operation done on this struct variable, the `printf` statement prints longer than its limit(i.e. 71 characters is the limit). Please see below the output obtained while debugging in gdb.

```
(gdb) s
cpyInParmsToCbl (in=0xffffb9f6, out=0x80ef320) at kc190Common.c:456
456       memset((void*)out, ' ', sizeof(kc910InputParms));
(gdb) printf "<%s>\n", out.inStream
<>
(gdb) n
458       strncpy(out->inStream+16, in->system_id,strlen(in->system_id));
(gdb) printf "<%s>\n", out.inStream
<                                                                       Pending>
```

Please notice above: There are 7 extra characters appended as "Pending" which prints the `out.inStream` upto 78 characters. This introduces flaw in the subsequent stage of the program.

Can someone please help me to understand this behavior and the correct way to use `memset` (if I am doing it wrong)?

If this is happening because the variable `out.inStream` has not been terminated by a null character `'\0'`, then my question is: Why it didn't print in the same way before `memset` ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using a C compiler and not a C++?

Comment: To reset the memory to which out points, just do:

    memset((void*)out, '\0', sizeof(kc910InputParms)).
Notice empty space character ' ' and '\0' are two different things.

Comment: @alk: Yes, I am pretty sure, I am using C compiler :)

Comment: @SelçukCihan: i understand but I didn't use `\0` in the `memset` because in the program, the `inStream` has to be used completely (with 70 chars). The program is built that way to handle the logic.

Comment: The `str*()` family of function expects C-"strings", that is: `0`-terminated `char`-arrays.

Comment: In C the cast here `memset((void*)out ...` is not needed.

Comment: @alk: That's interesting. You mean, in C, I shall not get any junk and thus there is no need of `memset` ?

Comment: I am referring to this cast `(void*)` not to the call itself.

Comment: @alk: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to the missing terminating nul. The reason why it worked before was due to the compiler setting the memory area to nuls, or just random luck.

You are also telling `strncpy` that there is space only for as many bytes as there are characters in the string so it is not adding the terminator. This is the wrong way to do it. You should tell `strncpy` how many bytes are available in the *destination*, not how many characters are in the *source*. In this case 54 (70-16). And you should explicitly set the last byte to nul for the case where the source is longer than 54 characters.

`printf` and other C string functions don't know anything about array sizes or memory allocations, they go by the terminating nul. So if you don't have it, they will continue until they find one, perhaps running out of the allocated memory space and causing undefined behavior. That is why you get more than 71 characters in output.

Comment: I understand your point on `strncpy` but in the post, the `strncpy` was not executed at all. The line `458` is just showed to tell the user that **this** line is going to execute as soon as the user hits `n`. But I didn't hit `n`, rather I used `printf` to know the value just after `memset`. So, going back to your first paragraph, do you mean to say that `printf` can print more than 71 characters further from the memory space of `inStream` ?

Comment: @Rohit `printf` will print until it runs into nul. It doesn't know anything about array sizes or anything.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me this. This makes sense. Please update your answer to include this part because my question was mainly focused around `printf` :)